# React not updating variable state in array of deep nested objects with filter function when updating with new data

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

I have the following code in React,

```
let [employee, setEmployee] = useState([])
let employeeList = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "email": "john@example.com",
                "status": "passed"
            },
            {
                "name": "Jane",
                "email": "jane@example.com",
                "status": "failed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When initilizing, we give as follows,

```
setEmployee(employeeList)
```

It shows both employees in table with status "passed" and "failed" in 2 rows correctly.

There is a selection box at the top which when selected with "passed",
we filter it with following function,

```
setEmployee(employee => employee[0].data.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed'));
```

I see the following filtered employee state variable,

```
// employee (state variable, see the original array of object of arrays is distorted here)
    [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "email": "john@example.com",
            "status": "passed"
        }
    ]
```

instead of,

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "email": "john@example.com",
                "status": "passed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm new to React states and unable to achieve above format. The original employee state variable should be intact structurally but only its deep array should be filtered. I guess there is some mistake I make in line,

```
setEmployee(employee => employee[0].data.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed'));
```

Any help is very appreciated. Please don't suggest advanced concepts like useMemo but let's modify it slightly to achieve what I want. Thanks.

Comment: I also face similar problem. When I make all changes in separate local variable and finally set the React state with `setEmployee(...employee)` I see the new data is not being updated by React but the existing array structure is distorted and view get broken. Not sure if this is a buggy state in ReactJs.

Comment: Don't you want the following in your state update?
`setEmployee(employee => [{
  data: employee[0].data.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed'));
}])`

Comment: @StuartNichols Thanks, great. this is the format that I wanted, but I see React nicely ignores it and doesn't give back the right format that you suggested and I expect. When used like I did, it returns back single filtered array that distorts source `employee` variable. I feel like **it's a nasty bug in React** the way it behaves.

Comment: @webblover, I'm really sorry, I don't understand. Does this modify the state value as you expect? If so, I can write an answer explaining more.

Comment: @StuartNichols sorry, I'm a bit late. Thanks for observation. Yes, as I said, your suggested format should be the right way to update UI in general but what happens behind the scenes, after we apply this line, `setEmployee(employee => [{   data: employee[0].data.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed')); }])` , I still see that the employee state changes is ignored by React altogether but if we used the incorrect approach like, `setEmployee(employee => employee[0].data.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed'));`, I can see the employee state is correctly updated but its format is wrong.

Comment: @webblover - If my answer below didn't work out for you, then please include your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/) for me to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- After deep analysis it's found that the state variable for Array of object of arrays is working normally for most functions like **.map()** and **.filter()** functions and subsequent array contains proper manipulated and filtered values. However, in the issue was caused by one other state variable that manipulated `employee` variable from somewhere in the large file that caused this employee variable's structure deformation when applying .map or .filter functions.

However following points need to be taken care seriously while developing ReactJs code,

- `console.log` won't output the expected values all the time in react
  because state variable is asynchronous unlike Angular or normal JS
  code snippet.
- `Array.push()` is not the right way to update the state variable with
  new records; this definitely collapses the expected Array values in
  real-time
- Use `let tempVar = employee.slice(0)` and then make the changes in
  **tempVar** variable, then use `setData` or `setEmployee` to update the new
  array values. That's the React way of pushing a new data as per the
  observations.
- Don't modify data in real-time like copy `arr[0]` as `arr[1]`, then
  setting it with `arr[1].name = 'New name', arr[1].age = 25`, then
  setting the new state like `setEmployee(arr)`  This will not update
  the employee state variable and can likely collapse the UI as happened in my case.
  The reason is that we do a lot in our JS snippet and specifically testing Angular apps with real-time mock data. This we shouldn't do post initializing state variables but do this even before init- ing so that raw JSON data can be manipulated with dummy values before assigning it the React's state variables.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that I am getting the question right, but it seems that the state you are returning when the selection box is checked, you are return the state in a different structure.

The filter function is returning an array, but with a different structure when you first initialized your state employee.

I tried it out myself, and successfully filtered the employeeList without modifying the original structure of your initial state.

```
    const handlePassed = () => {
    const newEmployeeList = employee.map((item) => {
        return {
            ...item,
            data: item.data.filter((employee) => employee.status === 'passed'),
        };
    });
    setEmployee(newEmployeeList);
};
```

I am not sure if this would be an efficient algorithm for updating your state, but I hope this is a starting point for figuring out your problem.

happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You can use the state setter form of the `setEmployee` in the original object structure.

Like so:

```js
setEmployee(prevEmployeeState => [{ data: prevEmployeeState[0].data.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed') }]);

// OR -- in case you have more than one object inside of the employeesList array:

setEmployee(prevEmployeeState => prevEmployeeState.map(employee => ({...employee, data: employee.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed')}));
```

The above line basically returns the filtered result as an array value of the property `data`.

Other approach would be to use `structuredClone` function to clone the object and update the state like you normally do, like so:

```js
const filteredResult = employee[0].data.filter((ele, i) => ele.status === 'passed');
const newEmployees = structuredClone(employee);
newEmployees[0].data = filteredResult;

setEmployee(newEmployees);
```

Note that I have used the `structuredClone` above to deep copy the old state object & to avoid any reference issues. Hope this helps. :)